# Android: ExifInterface. How to pass in file path?

Tags: java, android, gps

I want to use ExifInterface to get the GPS coordinates of a photo. I can't figure out how to format the filepath to pass into ExifInterface's constructor. I tried passing in objects of type `Uri`, `File`, and I also tried `Strings` where I typed in a known filepath.

---

I've created an Activity that calls the Camera app, then shows a form which displays the just-taken photo and lets the user enter some information in some `EditText`s. Then it sends the information from the `EditText`s back to the Main Activity using `i.putExtra()` (with `i` being an Intent). I'd like to send the GPS coordinates of the just-taken photo along with the other information.

Here is my code, where I create a `fileUri` to save the image to, before the Camera app is called:

```
public class AddPicActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
    private Uri fileUri;
    final Context context = this;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // create Intent to take a pic & return control to the calling app
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 

        // create a file to save the image
        fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);

        // set the image file name 
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); 

        // start the image capture Intent
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);

        // My layout file for this activity is "addflowlayout.xml"
        setContentView(R.layout.addflowlayout);

        // this is the submit button that's in R.layout.addflowlayout
        final Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.AddPicSubmitButton);

        // the submit button's click listener
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // gathering up the inputs that the user wrote in title, 
                // then description.
                final EditText titlefield = 
                    (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_Title);
                String title = titlefield.getText().toString();

                final EditText descfield = 
                    (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_Description);
                String desc = descfield.getText().toString();

                // gathering the latitude and longitude that get parsed 
                // out of the JPEG during the function photoloc():
                double x = Double.parseDouble(photoloc(fileUri)[0]); // latitude
                double y = Double.parseDouble(photoloc(fileUri)[1]); // longitude

                // Creating an intent to go back to MainActivity, which sends back 
                // the information from the EditText's title & description, plus 
                // the photo and the photo's latitude and longitude, and a boolean 
                // to tell MainActivity to acknowledge them all.
                Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("title", title);
                i.putExtra("desc", desc);
                i.putExtra("fileUri", fileUri);
                i.putExtra("lat", x);
                i.putExtra("long", y);
                i.putExtra("timeToAddMarker", true);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

    }

    // The function photoloc() is a function to take the image and parse out 
    // the latitude and longitude from the JPEG using ExifInterface.
    private String[] photoloc(String name){
        String[] locs = new String[2];
        // Use "fake" coordinates as defaults, until ExifInterface replaces them.
        locs[0]= "40.439338"; 
        locs[1]= "-79.919255";


        // Need to implement ExifInterface here using the try/catch. 
        // Need to figure out how to format the filename also.
        ExifInterface info = new ExifInterface(name);
        locs[0]=info.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE);
        locs[1]=info.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE);

        return locs;
    }

    /** Create a file Uri for saving an image or video */
    private static Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type){
          return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
    }

    /** Create a File for saving an image or video */
    private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type){
        // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted using
        // Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.
        File mediaStorageDir = new
            File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
            "MyCameraApp");
        // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared 
        // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
            if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
                return null;
            }
        }

        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = 
            new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE){
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + 
                File.separator +"IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
            System.out.println("The full name of mediaFile is "
                + mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_" 
                + timeStamp + ".jpg");
            tempname = "MyCameraApp/IMG_"+timeStamp+".jpg";
            System.out.println("tempname is "+tempname);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
        return mediaFile;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // Image captured and saved to fileUri specified in the Intent
                // shows the filename of the photo that was just taken.
                Toast.makeText(this, "Image saved to:\n" + data.getData(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                ImageView picview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.photo_zone);
                // set the just-taken photo as the content of the imageview in 
                // my layout with the ID "photo_zone"
                picview.setImageURI(fileUri);
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // User cancelled the image capture
            } else {
                // Image capture failed, advise user
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Did it work with a hard coded file path ?

Comment: Dear ToYonos, no, it did not work under any conditions. The app would crash at runtime, because (I think) the ExifInterface was being instantiated wrongly.

Comment: Dear ToYonos, I don't know how to make a stack trace because I'm a n00b :(      I'm using Eclipse.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors

Comment: Ah thanks, I didn't know that stack trace was the name for that. Anyway, after checking the stack trace, I found that the ExifInterface was returning "null" for GPS_LATITUDE and GPS_LONGITUDE. In this similar question, this person says the reason his ExifInterface was returning "null" is that he didn't pass in the filepath correctly. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19960790/exifinterface-returns-null-for-all-tags 
So I still don't understand how to pass in my filepath correctly into ExifInterface--that's what my original question was above.

Comment: Update: It turns out that there wasn't anything wrong with how I was passing in the filepath. The ExifInterface was returning "null" for GPS coordinates because my Camera app had geotagging turned off!